# How to calculate scriptPubkey?

Tags: transaction-input

Given an address (i.e. 1BnPVV5Tt25cxbDg6DqoxJunjSL8reCGz6), how can I calculate its scriptPubKey in order to build a transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to integrate it into a P2PKH tx.
You would have to base58decode the address, and then remove the checksum and the network byte. Then you can integrate it into a P2PKH tx in the std. way:

76 A9 14 <20 Bytes> 88 AC

I have two references with some code examples in C and python, that helped me at the time, when I had the same question :-)

> https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1543429.0
>
> https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1026.0

and some online "play tools" to verify:

> http://gobittest.appspot.com/Address
>
> http://lenschulwitz.com/base58